# Camel post servlet on karaf returns 405

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, apache-camel, apache-karaf

I am trying to setup a servlet using apache camel blueprint and running on karaf(jetty).

I got this in my "blueprint.xml":

```
<reference id="httpService" interface="org.osgi.service.http.HttpService" />

<bean class="org.apache.camel.component.servlet.osgi.OsgiServletRegisterer"
    init-method="register" destroy-method="unregister">
    <property name="alias" value="/Somepath" />
    <property name="httpService" ref="httpService" />
    <property name="servlet" ref="notifyServlet" />
</bean>

<bean id="notifyServlet"
    class="org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet" />

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <restConfiguration component="servlet" port="8080"
        contextPath="/Somepath" bindingMode="json">
        <dataFormatProperty key="prettyPrint" value="true" />
    </restConfiguration>
    <rest path="/restpath" consumes="application/json" produces="application/json">
        <post uri="/someuri">
            <to uri="direct:process" />
        </post>
    </rest>
[...]
</camelContext>
```

But when I try to call the servlet url with POST I always get a "405 Method not allowed" and in my Karaf logs I get the following:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Len': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source:java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@1e1ca883; line: 1, column: 5]
```

My parameters I send with the POST are "Len" and "Data".

Is there anything else I need to configure to make this work? Just can't figure it out..

Comment: Can you please indicate the URL you are hitting from your test? Please also include full details on the HTTP request you are performing (payload, headers, etc.). A dump of the HTTP request, or a curl command line would be great.